# отсутствует метод photos.get в android sdk vk api

Tags: android, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Мне нужно получить список всех фото пользователя и вывести их. В документации есть методы [`photos.get()`](https://vk.com/pages?oid=-1&p=photos.getAll) и [`photos().getAll()`](https://vk.com/pages?oid=-1&p=photos.getAll), но в android SDK я их не нашел.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
new VKRequest("users.get", VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.USER_IDS, res.userId, VKApiConst.FIELDS, "photo_200") );
```

Answer (score 2):

Это методы не Android SDK, а VkontakteSDK, так же это API для запросов к серверу, а не прямого вызова методов.

У класса `VKApiPhotos` из Android VK SDK, который в итоге вызывается по обращению к методу [`VKApi.photos()`](https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-android-sdk/blob/master/vksdk_library/src/main/java/com/vk/sdk/api/VKApi.java#L77) есть [следующие методы](https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-android-sdk/blob/master/vksdk_library/src/main/java/com/vk/sdk/api/methods/VKApiPhotos.java):`getUploadServer()`, `getWallUploadServer()`, `getMessagesUploadServer()`, `saveWallPhoto()`, `save()`, `saveMessagesPhoto()`, `getMethodsGroup()` - метода `getAll()` среди них нет.

Таким образом запрос строится по другому, например:

```
VKAPI.photos().getWallUploadServer();
```

либо через запросы, отправляемые непосредственно серверу, а не с помощью прямого вызова методов, если нужные запросы из VK API к серверу отсутствуют в Android VK SDK.

Comment: хм, почему-то этот метод описан на их сайте наряду с теми методами, которые вы перечислили . А есть ли метод в Android VK SDK для получения списка фото пользователя?

Comment: или как иначе можно получить этот список. я так понимаю, что-то вроде new Request("photos.get", params);

Comment: Я сам не работал с API vkontakte, поэтому точного ответа не скажу, но вы точно можете использовать универсальный Request с командами серверного API